# Tools needed to display 2D layers as a 3D stack in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d-analyst, 3d-map

What tools do I need to use to display 2D layers as a 3D stack in ArcGIS Pro?

Do I need to create a global scene first, or add an elevation attribute to the 2D layers, or is there a specific tool to achieve this directly?

I'm looking for something like this.

[image]

Comment: I would say what you are showing is not the product of a GIS but some sort of illustration package or even PowerPoint?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.